# Proxying a multipart request changes file byte array data

Tags: java, node.js, spring, express, proxy

I am trying to proxy a multipart file request with `express-http-proxy` to my Java Spring backend but for some reason the file byte array that Spring receives is not the same as the file that was uploaded. For example, a file whose byte array length is 3000 is transformed to about 6000. Any ideas why that's happening? Have you seen a similar issue ?

This is the snippet that proxies the request:

```
  var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
  var apiProxy = proxy('http://localhost:8080', {
      forwardPath: function (req, res) {
          return '/api/v2/photos/upload';
      }
  });

  app.all("/api/upload", apiProxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to self:

By default `express-http-proxy` encodes the request body as utf-8. The issue was that the request body was re-encoded, hence changing the data. Setting the `reqBodyEncoding` to `null` ensures that the request body is left intact:

```
var apiProxy = proxy('http://localhost:8080', {
      reqBodyEncoding: null,
      forwardPath: function (req, res) {
          return '/api/v2/photos/upload';
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This lib [doesn't support multipart file requests](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/issues/127).

Comment: Thanks Nathan! much better